# Can't deploy a contract that calls another contract

Tags: solidity, gas, contract-invocation, contract-deployment, out-of-gas

When I run the below code when connected to `geth --dev --mine`, the output is:

```
A transmitted, waiting for mining...
aAddress: 0xbaxxxxx4ae42d
B transmitted, waiting for mining...
bAddress: 0x47xxxxxfe8aa
53
```

When I run it on the live network when connected via `geth`, the output is:

```
A transmitted, waiting for mining...
aAddress: 0x04xxx76
B transmitted, waiting for mining...
[Error: The contract code couldn't be stored, please check your gas amount.]
```

When I replace the `a.a()` with `7` in the `b()` function, the output is:

```
A transmitted, waiting for mining...
aAddress: 0xbaxxxxxae42d
B transmitted, waiting for mining...
bAddress: 0x472xxxfe8aa
53
```

I'm running the following code with `node`:

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3();

web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://0.0.0.0:8545'));
web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.coinbase;

var aSource = 'contract A { function a() constant returns (uint) { return 7; } }';
var aCompiled = web3.eth.compile.solidity(aSource);
var aCode = aCompiled.A.code;
var aAbi = aCompiled.A.info.abiDefinition;

web3.eth.contract(aAbi).new({data: aCode}, function (err, contract) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return;
    } else if(contract.address){
        var aAddress = contract.address;
        console.log('aAddress: ' + aAddress);
        deployB(aAddress);
    } else {
        console.log("A transmitted, waiting for mining...");
    }
});

function deployB(aAddress) {
    var bSource = 'contract A { function a() constant returns (uint); }'+
    'contract B { A a; function B(A _a) { a = _a; } function b() returns (uint) { uint c = 46 + a.a(); return c; } }';
    var bCompiled = web3.eth.compile.solidity(bSource);
    var bCode = bCompiled.B.code;
    var bAbi = bCompiled.B.info.abiDefinition;
    var bContract = web3.eth.contract(bAbi);

    bContract.new(aAddress,{data: bCode}, function (err, contract) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            return;

        } else if(contract.address) {
            var bAddress = contract.address
            console.log('bAddress: ' + bAddress);
            var res = bContract.at(bAddress).b.call();
            console.log(res.toString());
        } else {
            console.log("B transmitted, waiting for mining...");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: If the value of `a` isn't correct, `a.a()` would be exception.  Is it really `aAddress: 0x04xxx76` ?  But I would try adding gas like `{data: bCode, gas:2000000}`

Comment: I'm obfuscating the address. Thanks, I'll try adding more gas.

Comment: Actually, before I try again, are you recommending I spend 2,000,000 gas? Isn't that over $4.50 USD?

Comment: Sorry you're trying on live network; I think the issues can be debugged on testnet with `geth --testnet` first, and there are faucets to get the ether.

Comment: @redsquirrel excessive gas is refunded, BTW.

Comment: Also, 2 million gas is presently about 0.04 ether - ~$0.30

Comment: @NickJohnson Yeah, I was looking at bad exchange rate data. :\

Comment: Let me guess, ether.fund? That place is a menace.

Comment: @NickJohnson Yes, it was ether.fund. Google searches love them, yet their data seems very stale. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to some pointers from @eth (see comments), and as the error message suggests, the solution is to simply send more gas. For some reason, the cost of deploying the contract that included the code `a.a()` was about 30,000 more expensive than the cost of the contract with a hard-coded `7`. Lesson learned!

I added the following code to more intelligently handle the gas cost:

```
var contractData = web3.eth.contract(bAbi).new.getData({data: bCode});
console.log("estimating gas price of creating B...");
var gasEstimate = web3.eth.estimateGas({data: contractData});
console.log(gasEstimate);

bContract.new(aAddress,{data: bCode, gas:gasEstimate+30000}, function (err, contract) {
```